# Get previous sibling until class is "something"

Tags: jquery, siblings

If I have a long list of `<li>` elements, when one is clicked, how can I get all sibling elements until one with a class name that contains a given string is reached?

Example:

```
<li>test</li>
<li class="one-two red">test</li>
<li class="green">test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li class="test">test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
```

In the example above, if `li.test` is clicked and the given string is `ne-tw`, would result in all elements in between including the clicked element (andSelf()) and the `one-two` class element.

Thank you.

Comment: The person who edited the question was wrong: I don't know the class name, I just know what it contains. In the example I gave, I knew it has the string: `ne-tw`, which is found in `one-two` class.

Answer (score 5):

jquery has a method for this:

```
var someclass = "one-two";
$("li").click(function(){
    var sel = $(this).prevUntil("." + someclass).andSelf();
    sel = sel.add(sel.eq(0).prev());
    console.log(sel);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil

Edit: code sample from comment:

```
var someclass = "one";
$("li").click(function(){
    var sel = $(this).prevUntil("[class*=" + someclass + "]").andSelf();
    sel = sel.add(sel.eq(0).prev());
    console.log(sel);
});
```

Comment: indeed. missed that part of the question.

Comment: If you include some way of doing that I'll remove my answer.  Can't see how it could improve this question in any way otherwise.

Comment: your answer is the way i would suggest doing it, it continues to work if you add multiple "one-two" elements.

Comment: i guess you could do it if you split it into two lines, updating answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nah, I like yours better.  Mine feels kind of like a hack :)

Comment: Hey, the problem is I don't know what the class is, I just know what it should contain.

Comment: Just declare a variable to store the class and include it in place of the class selector. updated example.

Comment: Tentonaxe, I don't know the class name, I only know that it contains something. Like if the string is "one" the first class to have that is what I want.

Comment: Ah, so for example the class is one-two, and you just know it should contain one. that is very interesting.... i would suggest .filter(), however that doesn't work very well in this situation since you want to know all of the elements in between the clicked element and the element that we find. I'm going to have to think on that a bit more... would you mind moving this to a discussion or something? maybe a post in the jQuery forums? its hard to discuss it here effectively.

Comment: actually. try this: `$(this).prevUntil("[class*=" + someclass + "]")` i placed in a full sample in answer for easy reference.